# How to empty(delete all contents) all files in a directory without deleting the files?

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix

Let's say i have 1000 `txt` files and I have to empty all the contents inside the file and keep just 1000 files with no content in it.
I was trying to use `cat /dev/null > *.txt` in shell but i was getting -`bash: *.txt: ambiguous redirect` and the files were not emptied.Any suggestions please ?

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? If you haven't even picked a tool to do it with, you are not ready for a question here.

Comment: @Jonrsharpe: I dint post what i have tried,Sorry for that ! Edited finally !

Comment: *"But It couldn't achieve it"* - what happened instead? Please give a [mcve]

Comment: Mate,I dont see my files are being emptied while using  cat /dev/null > *.txt and i was getting '-bash: *.txt: ambiguous redirect'.

Comment: So **put that information in the question**. I'd suggest reading [ask], which covers this sort of thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : Sorry about that ! Edited pal !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you would write

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write("")
```

Comment: You don't even need the `f.write("")`; you could just `pass`. Also the `glob` pattern is wrong.

Comment: @Cyphase: You're right! I fixed the pattern. (For testing I restricted this destructive code to `test.txt`.) And yes, you can simply use `pass`. But for the sake of readability and explicitness, I'd prefer `f.write("")`.

Comment: @Falko : Thanks Mate ! Solved !

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bash for loop.

```
for file in `ls`; do echo "" > $file; done
```

Now an explanation of the different parts:

```
for file in `ls`
```

This creates a for loop for all the files in the directory, assigning each filename in turn to the variable `$file`.

```
do echo "" > $file
```

This outputs an empty character string (`""`) into each file, overwriting its contents.

```
done
```

This ends the `for` loop.

Beware though, this is a destructive command and will clear every file in the directory!

Answer (score 0):

In shell you could empty down a file by echo an empty string to it:

```
echo '' > yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

One way like this to truncate the file:

```
> file
```